# SQL Server Generate Script To Fill Tables With Data From Other Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have two databases with identical tables, but one database's tables contains data while the other doesn't.  Is there a way in SQL Server to generate a script to fill the empty tables with data from the full tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the tables are identical and don't use an IDENTITY column, it is quite easy.

You would do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO TableB 
SELECT * FROM TableA
```

Again, only for identical table structures, otherwise you have to change the SELECT * to the correct columns and perform any conversions that are necessary.

Answer (score 3):

And, to add to the @WilliamD answer, if there is an IDENTITY column you can use a variation of the INSERT statement.

Assuming you have two columns (Col1 and Col2, with Col1 having IDENTITY property) in the tables, you can do the following:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableB ON

INSERT INTO TableB (col1, col2)
SELECT col1, col2 FROM TableA

SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableB OFF
```

It's necessary to list the columns in this situation.